Why does CreateProcessW give a error of 0x2
Im trying to create a debug process using CreateProcessW but it keeps giving me the error 0x2. I checked the error and the real error message is ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. I have checked that the file is there but it still gives me the same error. I am trying to open notepad.
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const char* debugee_path = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\notepad.exe";
    STARTUPINFOW startup_info = {};
    startup_info.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFOW);

    PROCESS_INFORMATION process_information = {};

    BOOL success = CreateProcessW(
        reinterpret_cast<const WCHAR*>(debugee_path),
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        FALSE,
        0,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        &startup_info,
        &process_information
    );
    if (!success)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}


You should be calling GetLastError if the return value of CreateProcessW returns false within your code -- it should not be an afterthought or an optional step.  See the documentation and the Return value description -- If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.

Using a cast to silence errors about incompatible pointers doesn't fix the real problem. It just tells the compiler to shut up. The reason is the cast doesn't change the format of the data that the pointer points to. The narrow character string is nonsense when read as a wide character string which the function needs.

Remove the reinterpret_cast and recompile the code.  What error(s) did the compiler give you?  Read the error message(s) carefully, because those errors are exactly the reason why the function will fail.

Using Visual Studio 2022 and removing the reinterpret_cast, the following error shows up when recompiling the code: error C2664: 'BOOL CreateProcessW(LPCWSTR,LPWSTR,LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,BOOL,DWORD,LPVOID,LPCWSTR,LPSTARTUPINFOW,LPPROCESS_INFORMATION)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char *' to 'LPCWSTR'.  If you get an error like this when it comes to character string/pointer arguments, you should never try to cast away the error.  Either provide the proper string/character pointer type, or call the function that accepts the types you are sending.

This is the problem: reinterpret_cast<const WCHAR*>(debugee_path). You are interpreting an ASCII string (1 byte per character) as a wchar string (2 bytes per character) which it is not.
To avoid this kind of mistakes don't use reinterpret_cast. Ever!
This should work:
const WCHAR* debugee_path = L"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\notepad.exe";
//                          ^
//                          |
//                          note the L prefix on the string literal

Or, as pointed by Remy Lebeau

use CreateProcessA instead


Or, use CreateProcessA instead.
